# Binding KendoGrid to a local object

Tags: data-binding, kendo-grid

I want to bind a KendoGrid to an object array so that it reflects what ever the user enters. The object will have two fields ExceptionName and ExceptionType. ExceptionType needs to be a dropdown of 5 items (this is working). The ExceptionName will be free text.

If I double click on the kendo grid, I can edit, but it does not reflects in the object. Same thing for Delete & new row. (So I think I am doing something wrong in the binding or in the declaration of the object)

Below, find a snippet of my code:

**Object array:**

```
   var authorizationInformation = [{
        id:1,
        exemptionName: "",
        exemptionType: "Unknown"
    }];
```

**KendoGrid:**

```
$("#AuthorizationGrid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [{
                field: "exemptionName", title: "Exemption Name"
            },
            {
                field: "exemptionType",
                title: "Exemption Type",
                template: function (value) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < exemptionTypeList.length; i++) {
                        if (exemptionTypeList[i].exemptionType == value.exemptionType) {
                            return exemptionTypeList[i].description;
                        }
                    }
                },
                editor: function (container) { 
                    var input = $('<input id="exemptionType" name="exemptionType">');
                    input.appendTo(container);

                    // initialize a dropdownlist
                    input.kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "description",
                        dataValueField: "exemptionType",
                        dataSource: exemptionTypeList 
                    }).appendTo(container);
                }
            },
            {
                command: "destroy"
            }],
            dataSource: authorizationInformation,
            editable: true,
            scrollable: false,
        });
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks, M